# loadrunner web_add_(auto)header() function and a proxy that creates saml tokens when testing webservices

Tags: web-services, proxy, saml, loadrunner

What is the difference between web_add_header() and web_add_auto_header() in LoadRunner?
My task is to send some header information in a web_custom_request against a proxy that on the basis of this information i.e. user name and autentication level generates a saml token that it is used furter in a request against a web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is context for the added header

- ..._add_auto_header() adds the header to all following requests
- ..._add_header() adds only to the next request

If you need to update tokens for every request then web_add_header() is the way to go.

The mad scientist in me would probably try experimenting with the header to see if I added a header with parameterization tags and then used lr_save_string() to assign the variable a value if that shift would be picked up when the header was sent.